# How can I iterate through a two-dimensional array in a snail mode, with a single cycle?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matrix, multidimensional-array, cycle

Given a *two dimensional array*, I would like to iterate through it in a **snail mode** and print out the elements using **one single cycle**.

For example if the given array is:

```
10 11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24
25 26 27 28 29
30 31 32 33 34
```

The program should print out:

```
10 15 20 25 30 31 32 33 34 29 24 19 14 13 12 11 16 21 26 27 28 23 18 17 22
```

So starting from the upper-left corner and arriving to the center of the array.

Comment: Is there any constraint on memory consumption/complexity?

Comment: does this help? http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-a-given-matrix-in-spiral-form/. They do it in O(mn) complexity.

Comment: There are no memory or running time constraints, but only the use of a single cycle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here is the solution with one for loop:**

It works only when the matrix is: **n >= m**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
//    int arr[4][3] = {{0, 9, 8} , {1, 10 , 7} , {2, 11, 6} , {3, 4, 5}};
//    int n = 4, m = 3;

    int arr[4][4] = {{0, 11, 10, 9} , {1, 12, 15, 8} , {2, 13, 14, 7} , {3, 4, 5, 6}};
    int n = 4, m = 4;

    int row = 0, col = 0, turn = 0;
    bool isTop = true;

    for(int nrElem = 0; nrElem <= (n*m); nrElem++)
    {
        //This part make the left, bottom, right part ( U form )
        if((row < n-1-turn) && (col != m-1) && (isTop == true))
        {
            cout << " " << arr[row][col];
            row++;
        } else {
            if((row == n-1-turn) && (col < m-1-turn))
            {
                cout << " " << arr[row][col];
                col++;
            } else {
                if((col == m-1-turn) && (row > 0))
                {
                    cout << " " << arr[row][col];
                    row--;
                } else {
                    isTop = false;
                }
            }
        }
        //

        //And this do the top backward parsing
        if((col > 0) && (isTop == false))
        {
            cout << " " << arr[row][col];
            col--;
        } else {
            if (isTop == false)
            {
                isTop = true;
                turn++;
                row += turn;
                col += turn;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do it with a single cycle without storing additional matrices. The following code assumes that you can use `std::vector` from `C++11` and is based on the example from [geeks for geeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-a-given-matrix-in-spiral-form/). Ofcourse, the algorithm works without `std::vector` as well. Furthermore, this snail goes clockwise and as an exercise you should change it to make counter clockwise :).  *[I did not compile the code]*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void printSnail(vector<vector<int>> const &matrix)
{
  size_t nRow = matrix.size();       // Number of rows that are not printed yet
  size_t nCol = matrix[0].size();    // Number of columns that are not printed yet

  size_t k = 0;
  size_t l = 0;

  // Print all elements in the matrix
  while (k < nRow and l < nCol)
  {
    // Print first row of remaining rows
    for (size_t idx = l; idx < nCol; ++idx)
      cout << matrix[k][idx] << ' ';
    ++k;

    // Print last column of remaining columns
    for (size_t idx = k; idx < nRow; ++idx)
      cout << matrix[idx][nCol - 1] << ' ';
    --nCol;

    // Print last row of remaining rows
    if (k < nRow)
    {
      for (size_t idx = nCol - 1; idx >= l; --idx)
        cout << matrix[nRow - 1][idx] << ' ';
      --nRow;
    }

    // Print the first column of the remaining columns
    if (l < nCol)
    {
      for (size_t idx = nRow - 1; idx >= k; --idx)
        cout << matrix[idx][l] << ' ';
      ++l;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to implement it in Javascript

```
snail = function(arr) {
    let [y, x] = [0, 0];
    let [rs, ls, us, ds] = [0, 0, 0, 0]
    let [xLimit, yLimit] = [arr.length, arr.length];
    let dir = 'right'
    const res = []
    const len = arr[0].length * arr[0].length
    const rowLen = arr[0].length
    while (res.length < len) {
        res.push(arr[y][x])
        switch (dir) {
            case 'right':
                if (x + 1 < xLimit) {
                    x++
                } else {
                    dir = 'down'
                    yLimit = rowLen - ds
                    rs++
                    y++
                }
                break;
            case 'down':
                if (y + 1 < yLimit) {
                    y++
                } else {
                    dir = 'left'
                    xLimit = ls
                    ds++
                    x--
                }
                break;
            case 'left':
                if (x > xLimit) {
                    x--
                } else {
                    dir = 'up'
                    yLimit = ds
                    ls++
                    y--
                }
                break;
            case 'up':
                if (y > yLimit) {
                    y--
                } else {
                    dir = 'right'
                    xLimit = rowLen - rs
                    us++
                    x++
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
    return res
}
```

It's not using any built-in Javascript function so it can be translated to any language

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution to your problem:

- Keep a 2D array(`checkIfVisited`) of the same size(all cells initialized to `0`) of that your array, in order to keep track of the cells that are already visited. If `(i,j)` is `1` then it means that the cell in the original has already been visited.
- We iterate the whole array spirally with the help of the `dir` variable which keeps track of which direction we are currently traversing.
- `dir` = `0` means moving downwards, `1` means moving rightwards, `2` means moving upwards, `3` means moving leftwards.
- We change directions when either `i` and `j` goes out of limits or when the next cell to be traversed has already been traversed before by doing a lookup from the `checkIfVisited` array.

I have a simple C++ implementation of the above algorithm:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    int arr[5][5] = {10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
                     15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
                     20, 21, 22, 23, 24,
                     25, 26, 27, 28, 29,
                     30, 31, 32, 33, 34};

    int checkIfVisited[5][5] = {0,0,0,0,0,
                                0,0,0,0,0,
                                0,0,0,0,0,
                                0,0,0,0,0,
                                0,0,0,0,0};
    int i,j,dir,countVisited;
    dir = 0;
    countVisited = 0;
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    while(countVisited<5*5)
    {
        cout<<arr[i][j]<<" ";
        checkIfVisited[i][j]=1;
        if(dir==0)
        {
            countVisited++;
            if(i+1>4 || checkIfVisited[i+1][j]==1){
                dir=1;
                j++;
            }
            else
                i++;
        }
        else if(dir==1)
        {
            countVisited++;
            if(j+1>4 || checkIfVisited[i][j+1]==1){
                dir=2;
                i--;
            }
            else
                j++;
        }
        else if(dir==2)
        {
            countVisited++;
            if(i-1<0 || checkIfVisited[i-1][j]==1){
                dir=3;
                j--;
            }
            else
                i--;
        }
        else
        {
            countVisited++;
            if(j-1<0 || checkIfVisited[i][j-1]==1){
                dir=0;
                i++;
            }
            else
                j--;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:** `10 15 20 25 30 31 32 33 34 29 24 19 14 13 12 11 16 21 26 27 28 23 18 17 22`